# Firebase email and password authentication fails

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

Firebase email and password authentication fails even though I have it activated in the Firebase console and the code for that activity is from the github sample.

Also I have added a user manually so everything is there.

I am doing as in this link describes:
[Firebase instructions](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/EmailPasswordActivity.java)

**Update**

Here is the code for the signing in method:

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
     .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
          Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

          // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
          // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
          // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
          if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail", task.getException());
            Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }

          // [START_EXCLUDE]
          hideProgressDialog();
          // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
      });
```

**Update 2**

I have also tried to do this and I does not work either:

```
private void signInBeta(String email,String password){
  Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://prechecker-46a58.firebaseio.com/");

  ref.authWithPassword(String.valueOf(email), String.valueOf(password), new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
      System.out.println("User ID: " + authData.getUid() + ", Provider: " + authData.getProvider());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
      System.out.print("\nSOMETING WENT WRONG\n");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you imported google-services.json file?

Comment: Yes the JSON is in my project. I am also running this on a device.

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: Sure but the code is exactly as the Firebase documentation tells you to do. Is there any specific that can be interesting to see?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it fails? It there an exception? Did you step through the code in a debugger? Where do email and password come from? Did you try with hardcoded email and password?

Comment: What I mean by failing is that I have created an account in the firebase console and that the signing in don't work when I provide the correct email and password

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an emulator please use the latest device, because older than Pixel XL devices won't work, You will get an error message as: "Authentication failed." including Pixel XL.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you haven't enable oAuth for login.
Try adding OAuth Client ID in https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?

Comment: No SHA fingerprint are added

Comment: I will create SHA fingerprint and the  create Auth ID

Comment: Now I have added SHA in my firebase console for the project and the JSON file have it to. I still don't get it to worn

Comment: On the Sign in method tab, have you enable the Email/password sign-in ? read more at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth

Comment: Look at my update how the signing in  code looks like

Comment: Have added more code with another take on the signin method but still dont work. Just getting error

Answer (score 0):

Firebase does not accept if the email id is not in the format of email id and it does not accept password with shorter length. My Problem is also the same, but the solution might seems sense less to you. I hope this may helps you. While giving email and password make sure that email id has '@domain.com' for example 'leoXXXX@gmail.com' and your password must atleast has length of 10.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using virtual device to run your app,check if Google Services are up to date or switch to your personal device with all updates.

Answer (score -1):

i spent a whole day trying to figure out, turns out u need a password length of 6+